# Spring Data Mongodb Cross store:: With MySQL @RelatedDocument(s) not updating

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-document

I am using Spring Data Mongodb and Spring data JPA module for MySQL.

I have successfully configured as suggested in the reference document.
I am able to save but not able to update the mongodb "RelatedDocuments"
though I am successfully able to update the MYSQL fields.

The entity relationship is like

User(Mysql) has Addresses(Mongo) > Has list of Address (quite similar to the survey example in reference.

**My situation is exactly similar to http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?126897-Using-Spring-Data-with-MongoDB-and-MySQL**

The versions I am using are as follows

```
spring-data.mongodb.version = 1.1.0.M1
spring.version = 3.1.2.RELEASE
    spring.data.jpa.version = 1.1.0.RELEASE

hibernate.entitymanager.version = 4.1.4.Final
hibernate.jpa-api.version = 1.0.1.Final (using JPA 2.0)

    aspectj.version = 1.6.12
```

Please could somebody point out what I might be missing, config files are as below

```
<!-- Activate Spring Data JPA repository support -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.domain.domain.*.repo" factory-class="com.mydomainit.domain.repo.BaseJpaRepositoryFactoryBean"/>
```

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"
    p:persistenceUnitName="spring-jpa" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateVendor" />

<bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:showSql="true" p:generateDdl="false"
    p:database="MYSQL" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

The MongoDB config is as below

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.domain.*.mongorepo" repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl"
    factory-class="com.domain.mongorepo.CommonMongoRepoFactoryBean" />

<mongo:mongo id="mongoRef" host="${mongo.host.name}" port="${mongo.host.port}">
    <mongo:options connections-per-host="8" threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4" connect-timeout="1000" max-wait-time="1500"
        auto-connect-retry="true" socket-keep-alive="true" socket-timeout="1500" slave-ok="true" write-number="${mongo.db.w}" write-timeout="${mongo.db.wtimeout}"
        write-fsync="${mongo.db.fsync}" />
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongo.db.name}" username="${mongo.db.username}" password="${mongo.db.password}"
    mongo-ref="mongoRef" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" c:mongoDbFactory-ref="mongoDbFactory" c:mongoConverter-ref="mappingConverter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.crossstore.MongoDocumentBacking" factory-method="aspectOf">
    <property name="changeSetPersister" ref="mongoChangeSetPersister" />
</bean>
<bean id="mongoChangeSetPersister" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.crossstore.MongoChangeSetPersister">
    <property name="mongoTemplate" ref="mongoTemplate" />
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation in Internet is quite old, which makes it is difficult to configure; there are many dependencies between libraries and some apis changed. I managed to make it work as follows. I hope it helps:

**pom.xml**

```
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <querydsl.version>2.9.0</querydsl.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <mongodb.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</mongodb.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${mongodb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-cross-store</artifactId>
        <version>${mongodb.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**databaseContext.xml**

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="databasename" />
</bean>
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.yourcompany.repository.mongodb" />

<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator" />
<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.crossstore.MongoDocumentBacking" factory-method="aspectOf">
    <property name="changeSetPersister" ref="mongoChangeSetPersister" />
</bean>
<bean id="mongoChangeSetPersister" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.crossstore.MongoChangeSetPersister">
    <property name="mongoTemplate" ref="mongoTemplate" />
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

**Product Object (to be stored in MySQL)**

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; // MySQL + MongoDB
    private double value; // MySQL
    @RelatedDocument
    private ProductInfo info; // MongoDB
}
```

**ProductInfo Object (to be stored in MongoDB)**

```
@Document
public class ProductInfo {
    @Id
    public ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

**Product Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>{}
```

**JUnit Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestApplicationContext.class })
@TestExecutionListeners({ TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
public class JournalMongoDBServiceIT  {
    @Resource
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void crossStoreProduct(){
        Product product = new Product();
        ProductInfo info = new ProductInfo();
        info.setName("Test");
        info.setDescription("Test Product");
        product.setInfo(info);
        productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void crossStoreProductFindAndUpdate(){
        Product product = productRepository.findOne(32L);
        product.setValue(999L);
        product.getInfo().setDescription("Updated description");
        productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have refered documentntion given below 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.cross.store

Is that necessary to provide plugin configuration which has aspectj compile time configuration?

I was trying this as a independent application, Have you share some working code here.